# MKStoreKit how to change the purchase confirm dialog title

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am using in-app purchase to buy a set audiobooks.
I am using MKStoreKit wrapper for in-app purchase. my products are of non consumable type.therefore bought only once.
However whenever i press the buy button the message "Do you want to buy one {audiobook name}  for {price}" .
how to change this message?

if any one has used MKStoreKit, how to know if the purchase is completed.(I need to change the title of button only if the purchase is complete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure, but I think you can't customize this alert, it's specific to Apple.
And about how to know if the purchase is completed, I suggest you to take a look at [this website](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/), and specially at this method :

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

You also have to call this before ( again, take a look on the website above ) :

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

When the transaction.transactionState is SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased, this means that the transaction is completed.

Hope it helps

Comment: this method is implemented in a class called MKStoreObserver and i need to change the buy button to read in a viewcontroller called booksList.So how can i make so that this method fires up in booksList itself? i tried implementing MKStoreObserver as a delegate to booksList but still this method is not firing from here

Comment: do you have set bookslist as a TransactionObserver of the defaultQueue ( like I wrote it on the answer ) ?